# ActionFilterAttribute is not called

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have this custom action filter:

```
public class PermissionChecker: ActionFilterAttribute
{
    private int _permissionId { get; set; }
    private IUserSelectorService _userService { get; set; }

    public PermissionChecker(int permissionId)
    {
        _permissionId = permissionId;
        _userService = new UserSelectorService();
    }

    public PermissionChecker(int permissionId, IUserSelectorService userService)
    {
        _permissionId = permissionId;
        _userService = userService;
    }

    public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        base.OnActionExecuting(actionContext);
    }
}
```

and I set it in my action:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    [PermissionChecker(1)]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

but it is not working! the code doesn't pass in onActionExecuting even in constructor of PermissionChecker.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The signature of your OnActionExecuting is not correct, it should have [ActionExecutingContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.actionexecutingcontext%28v=vs.108%29.aspx):

*Provides the context for the ActionExecuting method of the ActionFilterAttribute class.*

```
public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext){
    base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
}
```

Comment: that is not mvc3 specific, it applies to mvc4 as well

Comment: added link to msdn reference

Comment: Oh yeah, I was using ActionFilterAttribute of System.Web.Http.Filters and not of System.Web.Mvc. Thank.